# PHP Notice : undefined offset 381 and 382 with in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

This code is showing an error like PHP Notice : undefined offset 381.
And offset number increases as loop runs.

```
$marks=0;
$correct = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $exam_name = $row['exam_name'];
    $exam_percentage = $row['exam_pass_percentage'];
    if($row['a_sortorder'] == $json['responses'][0][1][$row['qid']]){
        $marks = $marks + 4;
        $correct++;
    }
}
```

Don't know what to do ?

Comment: `$json['responses'][0][1]['381']` doesn't exist. Check with *isset* first if it exists. `if( isset($json['responses'][0][1][$row['qid']]) && $row['a_sortorder ....`

Comment: I found the solution . in $json['responses'][0][1][$row['qid']] , $row['qid'] should be q.$row['qid'] ....the qid was changed by third party application and it concatinate q with qid.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$marks=0;
$correct = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $exam_name = $row['exam_name'];
    $exam_percentage = $row['exam_pass_percentage'];
    if(isset($row['a_sortorder']) && isset($json['responses'][0][1][$row['qid']]) && $row['a_sortorder'] == $json['responses'][0][1][$row['qid']]){
        $marks = $marks + 4;
        $correct++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for helps . I have solved it.The problem was with $row['qid'] and [1]. $row['qid'] is  a integer but key where i am using $row['qid'] was a varchar type key like q381 and i was using only 381. So i changed $row['qid'] with q.$row['qid'] and it works.
The other problem was with  1 is that this key was also changing so i replaced it with corresponding variable and it is working properly

Comment: Are you think this can be helpful to someone except you?

Comment: It may help....someone can use it as reference if he/she is making similar mistake ..I don't know about undefined offset x,where x can be any value, earlier but now ii have some idea about it  so for someone who don't know about undefined offset it may help